# ES6 modules: How are cyclic dependencies supposed to work, per spec? (webpack vs babel)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I recently upgraded my app to webpack 2. Since webpack 2 now supports ES6 modules,  I configured my babel es2015 preset with *{modules: false}* to let webpack handle the imports directly.

There are circular dependencies in my app, which Babel handled just fine, but webpack 2, by itself, did not. I looked into this, and found that the Code that Babel generates looks, essentially, like this:

*A.js*

```
exports.someFunc = someFunc;
var _b = __webpack_require__(1071);
// ....more imports
```

*B.js*

```
var _a = __webpack_require__(256); 

// => _a.someFunc() can now be called immediately as part of the module side effect, i.e. used as a decorator.
```

This works, because Babel moves the *exports* assignment in A.js to the top.

Letting webpack handle the loading, the code generated will be like this:

*A.js:*

```
var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__B__ = __webpack_require__(1071);
exports.someFunc = someFunc;
```

Thus, when module B first runs, it cannot access `someFunc` yet. To be clear, that's fine if `someFunc` is only used later, but not if `someFunc` is a decorator used during module initialization.

Who is correct? Babel or Webpack?

Comment: Depends on how you did define/declare the function, how you did export it, and what the entry point of your modules is.